# OpenJPA adding 1 <> 1 to WHERE clause

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

OpenJPA is adding "1 <> 1" to my WHERE clause.  Any idea why?  I listed some sample code & Sql below

```
 //Criteria Query
_PredicateList.add(
    _CriteriaBuilder.equal(
            _RootClass.get(Test_.Data)   
            ,"XXX"                                                                                      )
        );      

//sql snippet that is generated
t0.Data= 'XXX' AND 1 <> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition you're building has probably no chance of evaluating to *true* and OpenJPA detects it at the query setup time. This can be caused by incompatible types being compared (in your case) or for a number of different reasons in other cases (i.e. "is null" condition on a non-null column, comparison to a string constant greater than max length allowed for that column, etc.).

Why such a strange condition? Probably to give a hint to the developer that there's a logical mistake in the query (and not to fail with a runtime exception). Less likely, for performance reasons. Also, not all SQL dialects support boolean literals.